# Python Simple PiggyBank Program

Tags: file, python-3.x, input, output, converters

This is my Python Program that I have been having some issues with:

## -*- coding: cp1252 -*-

```
from time import gmtime, strftime
print("Welcome to the PiggyBank version 1.")
num_write = int(input("How much money would you like to store in your PiggyBank?"))
f = open("PiggyBanks_Records.txt", "w")
current_time = strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S", gmtime())

convert_1 = str(current_time)
convert_2 = str(int(num_write))
add_1 = ("\n" + convert_1 + "   £" + convert_2)
add_2 = ("\n" + add_1) #Tried to make it so new line is added every time the program is run
final_record = str(add_2)

print("Final file written to the PiggyBank: " + final_record)
#Write to File
f.write(final_record)
f.close()
```

Right now whenever the program writes to the file it over-writes. I would preferably would like to keep, like a history of the amounts added. If anyone can help so the string that needs to be written to the .txt file goes down by one line and essentially keeps going for ever. I am also open to any suggestion on how I can shorten this code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to open your file with `append` mode :

```
f = open("PiggyBanks_Records.txt", "a")
```

Answer (score 0):

Using the 'w' write option with open automatically looks for the specified file, and deletes its contents if it already exists (which you can read about [here](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/inputoutput.html#reading-and-writing-files)) or creates it if it doesn't.  Use 'a' instead to add / append to the file.